# Android Library (CardsLib) - No resource identifier for attribute 'list_card_layout_resourceID'

Tags: android

In my search for an easy way to display a Card UI in android I found "[CardsLib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)". I have several days trying to test the demo they offer on github but I can not run it. This is the error I have:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'list_card_layout_resourceID' with value '@layout/list_card_thumbnail_layout').
```

IMAGE

```
http://i.imgur.com/xA3y3a7.png
```

I'm using IntelligIdea 13. Below are the steps I am doing.

1. import the Card Library Demo found in this link: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/tree/master/demo
2. Add android-support-v4 to Card Library Demo
3. import CardsLib library as a module
4. Add CardLib as a dependency to Card Library Demo
5. compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to do in the other way:

1. checkout full git repository (https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)
2. import in idea `settings.gradle` file from root folder

You should be able compile and run demo after